# Is it possible to filter for exported/printed photographs in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, workflow, photo-management

To keep track of the pics that I print or export I am currently adding a tag (such as "print") and using Smart collections which filter on these tags. This has a major failure point, in requiring that I remember to add the tag :-)

Is there a native solution in Lightroom to filter all the pics that have been printed?

I am currently using version 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Lightroom doesn't offer the native ability to filter all printed/exported images. For printed images your current system seems to be the best solution although depending on your workflow using publish services may offer a better solution for keeping track of exported images.

Answer (score 0):

I use colored flags (R Y G B, purple). Eg. I mark an image with a pre-determined colored flag to indicate that it is an exported file. You can access these flags directly or through shortcuts 6,7, 8, 9...no shortcut for purple though.

Comment: This seems to be a similar solution to the one that the OP has said they already use.

Comment: @damned truths: No, it is not. Adding a tag to an image you exported is not as easy as setting a color flag.  For adding a tag, you change over to library module - when you want to see exported pics, it is a laborious process. You can add a color tag as soon as you export with just a keystroke and later user filters to select exported images.

Comment: It still requires remembering to do it, which is the main reason given for not using tags. It isn't automatic.